# calculating an algorithm time in prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, systemtime

I am solving Bridge and Torch puzzle by PROLOG. As I am trying different search methods, I need to find the calculation time. I mean the start time and the end time of solving the problem by the algorithm.

Can I have access to System time from Prolog ? How?

Comment: Have you looked at SWI Prolog's `time/1` predicate?

Comment: Thanks I used `get_time(T)` and it solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I calculated overall Time in a predicate using `get_time(T)` as this:

```
print_solution :- 
  **get_time(T1),**
  init(State), 
  solve(State,Solution,EndState), 
  writeln('Start state:'),
  writeln(State),
  writeln('Solution:'),
  writeln(Solution),
  writeln('Final state:'),
  writeln(EndState),
  **get_time(T2),**
  **DeltaT is T2- T1,**
  **write('time: '), write(DeltaT), write('  ms.\n'), nl.**
```

Comment: It may be interesting, in comparison, to remove the `**` items and call, `time(print_solution)` to see what you get. It will show the time as well as other profile information such as number of inferences, etc. You might be able then avoid adding extra timer code to your predicate.

Comment: WAW! GREAT! I got it. :-) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using `get_time/1` for assessing the execution time of algorithms does not calculate the execution time of the algorithm in isolation, but of your entire computer's process stack. E.g., if your OS decides to run some process in the background, this can already change the time delta considerably.

SWI-Prolog has dedicated support for tracking the time spend on calculating *all* called predicates. For this you need to (1) import library `statistics` and (2) enclose the predicate you want to profile in `profile/1`.

For example:

```
:- use_module(library(statistics)).

run_test:-
  profile(my_predicate(MyArgument)).
```

Hope this helps!